# how to run python file on mininet

Tags: python, mininet, ryu

```
/Desktop/mininet/examples$ sudo python tree1024.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tree1024.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mininet.cli import CLI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mininet'
```

Whenever I am trying to run python file it is throwing this error. can please some guide how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone Mininet and export the path

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
cd mininet
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/mininet/mininet:
```

Then run the script with python3

```
sudo python3 tree1024.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the mininet is not fully installed, Try to install it through the clone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).